# Laravel stop queue job if exception is thown

Tags: php, laravel

I wonder how I can stop a queue job in laravel if a exception is thrown.

```
public function handle()
{

       try {
          //STEP 1 tasks
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
           Log::error('Error message: '.$e);
       }

       try {
          //STEP 2 tasks
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
           Log::error('Error message: '.$e);
       }


}
```

Now lets say that **STEP 1** fails and a exception is thown loggin the error.

Will my job still continue and try to execute **STEP 2** ?

I want to make sure if **STEP 1** fails then **STEP 2** should not be executed.

I dont want to put everything inside the same try catch.

Comment: You can re-throw the exception after logging. Inside the first catch, after you log it, do `throw $e` and it'll halt.

Answer (score 0):

Re-throw exception after you logged it. In this case job will be interrupted and second step wont be executed.

You can also [add settings to the job](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#max-job-attempts-and-timeout) like number of attempts, execution timeout and so on in case you want to give a job few more attempts to execute successfully.

```
public function handle()
{

   try {
      //STEP 1 tasks
   } catch (\Exception $e) {
       Log::error('Error message: '.$e);
       throw $e;
   }

   try {
      //STEP 2 tasks
   } catch (\Exception $e) {
       Log::error('Error message: '.$e);
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fail your job after a certain condition or statement
try using :

```
$this->fail()
```

On the line you want to fail your job.

Like

```
public function handle()
{
   $hitSomeApi = 'www.example.com/api';
   if($hitSomeApi['header_code'] == 500 ) {
       $this->fail(); 
      //this will fail your job and stops it's further execution
      //And also send the job in failed_jobs table.
   } else {
       //do something
   }
   //do something
   //...
   //...
   //...
   //these line will only be executed it $this->fail() is not called.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach

```
public function handle()
{

      //Assign a variable which determine if step 1 is success
      $step_1_success = true;
       try {
          //STEP 1 tasks
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //if catch error occured set it to false
            $step_1_success = false;
           Log::error('Error message: '.$e);
       }

       //before running step 2 check if step 1 is success base on the created variable `$step_1_success`
       if ($step_1_success) {
         try {
            //STEP 2 tasks
         } catch (\Exception $e) {
             Log::error('Error message: '.$e);
         }
      }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you simply wants to know that job is failed you can try this.

```
  public function failed(Exception $exception)
    {
        // Send user notification of failure, etc...
    }
```

If you want to delete the job permanently you can use `delete()` method. You job will be permanently deleted.

```
public function handle()
{

       try {
          //STEP 1 tasks
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
           $this->delete();
           Log::error('Error message: '.$e);
       }

       try {
          //STEP 2 tasks
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
           Log::error('Error message: '.$e);
       }


}
```